# Как правильно организовать клиентов в symfony3?

Tags: php, framework, symfony, symfony3

Планирую сайт торговой интернет площадки "для себя" для самообразования.
Думается будет общий *back-end* для сайта и для панели управления на **symfony3**, только разные контроллеры. Так вот возник вопрос, как правильно сделать авторизацию сотрудников в консоли управления и авторизацию клиентов в личном кабинете на сайте?
Сейчас начинаю разбираться и есть **FOSUserBundle** от которого унаследован класс являющийся по сути описанием сотрудника с доступом к панели управления. Вся авторизация идёт где-то внутри этого класса и и его обёрток. А как теперь правильно отделить клиентские аккаунты и так же авторизовать их уже на сайте?

Либо я не правильно изначально что-то понимаю...
Подскажите как "правильно" это делается?

Answer (score 0):

Для разделения пользователей вы можете воспользоваться ACL моделью (не рекомендуется в виду сложности) или Ролевой системой с использованием голосующих классов (Symfony Voters). Для каждой категории пользователей необходимо определить их зоны доступа и, тем самым, разделить их. Вам нужно расширить свои знания о компоненте безопасности (Symfony Security Component). Рекомендую досконально изучить документацию, особенно сопутствующие статьи.

Есть готовое решение от Sonata с их SonataAdminBundle в связке с SonataUserBundle (который, к слову, может наследовать FOSUserBundle на ваше усмотрение). По своему опыту могу сказать, что хорошо и грамотно настроить эту связку 2 года назад было сложно, 4 года назад невыносимо сложно. Теперь дела обстоят намного лучше, но кое-какие проблемы все еще тянутся с тех времен. (много доков на английском языке)

Также рекомендую вам ознакомится с готовыми решениями (с использованием компонентов Symfony) интернет магазинов, такими как Sylius, Prestashop.